# ant jar's mainclass

Tags: java, ant, jar

how do i set the Main-Class attribute of my jar in ant?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a manifest:

```
<manifest file="build/MANIFEST.MF">
  <attribute name="Main-Class"
             value="foo.FooMain" />
</manifest>
<jar destfile="build/foo.jar"
     manifest="build/MANIFEST.MF">
  <fileset dir="build/classes" />
</jar>
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't set the main class for Java modules.  In order to set a JAR file's ModuleMainClass attribute, you have to use the exec task to manually call the JAR executable with appropriate arguments.

Comment: Opened [Bug ID 62772](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62772) to update the JAR task with modular JAR file support.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify it in the manifest by using the [Manifest](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifest.html) nested element of the [Jar](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) task. Set `Main-Class` to the required class.